# How do you reset defaults for VI?

Tags: vi, editing

I am currently using VI on a remote host and for some reason a number of the commands are mapped incorrectly.  For example when pressing lower case **x**, instead of it deleting the character under the cursor it actually deletes the character two spaces before the cursor, so if the following text is entered *BOTY* and I have the cursor over the *T* instead of removing *T* the *O* will be removed making the word *BTY*.  Also when inserting text, instead of VI inserting the character under the cursor it will enter the the character two spaces before the cursor so if I have the following text *HT* and I want to insert *ML* instead of writing *HTML* VI will write *HMLT*.

Does anyone know what would be causing this and how I can fix it or how to reset all settings in VI to default because this is probably not the only items mapped incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like it might be a terminfo issue. Is vi the only program you're having troubles with?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to reset all things to default, it's very simple, just :set all&

Answer (score 3):

In your home, look at a file called .exrc (.vimrc for vim). It contains vi configuration, if you clear it (make a backup before), vi will return to default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are using the classic "VI" instead of "VIM (VI IMproved)". If you are root on the machine try installing VIM. I experience this behaviour on Ubuntu every time after a fresh os install.